# Understanding algebraic Multiplicity in two ways

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenfunctions

There are two ways to define the algebraic multiplicity of a eigenvalue.

1. The dimension of its generalized eigenspace.
2. The multiplicity as a root of the characteristic polynomial.

I just wonder why these two statements are equivalent on complex vector spaces. Can anybody give me a brief explanation?

Comment: Consider Jordan normal form.

Comment: Consider nilpotent matrices, their characteristic equations and their generalized eigenspaces / generalized kernels, to more easily see what's going on. Then realize that basically the same thing is going on in any other case.